# ZSH - output whole history?

Tags: zsh

I recently switched from bash to zsh. In bash, one way (besides recursive search) that I used to find previously-run commands was `history | grep whatever`, where `whatever` is the bit of command I remember.

In zsh, this isn't working. `history` returns only a few items, even though my `.zsh_history` file contains many entries, which I have configured it to do.

How can I output my whole history, suitable for searching with `grep`?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417094/221410

Answer (score 173, accepted):

History accepts a range in zsh entries as `[first] [last]` arguments, so to get them all run `history 0`.

To get the zsh help (at least with mind) type `Alt-h` over the history command and this will bring up the help for built-ins.

Comment: Great! That's an annoying default for me, though, so I'm adding this to my aliases file: `alias history="history 0"`

Comment: Not that it matters but the history list starts at 1 and not 0.

Comment: I'm using this alias myself: `alias h='history 1 | grep'`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: my `~/.zsh_history` has 10066 lines, but `history 0` (or its equivalent, `fc -l 0`), only prints out 4999 lines.

Comment: To the `history 1 | grep` people, I hope you know about `ctrl+r` - best trick/shortcut ever!

Comment: @EmilVatai or even better [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search)

Comment: How can I get the `history` command manual? I'm in Mac, and `man history` display BSD command builtin

Comment: Great tip about `ctrl-r` from @EmilVatai just be aware that if there's a single command or script found it will be immediately executed, may not be something you want

Comment: I am using `alias history="history 0 | less +G"`

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer is correct, but it’s worth noting that you don’t *need* to call the external `grep` binary to do the search, since that ability is baked in.  I have this function defined in my `.zshrc`:

```
histsearch() { fc -lim "*$@*" 1 }
```

Notes:

- `fc` is the zsh builtin that controls the interactive history.  `history` is equivalent to `fc -l`.
- The `-m` flag requires a pattern, which must be quoted.
- The `-i` flag adds a timestamp.
- `fc` has many more tricks up its sleeve (e.g. limiting the search to internal history for the current session).  See the `zshbuiltins(1)` man page or [the official documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc).

*Edit (2021-01-27):*

A major advantage of using this method over just grepping the zsh history file is you get human-readable timestamps via `-i`. Of course, this only works if you’ve enabled the saving of timestamps to the history file in the first place:

```
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

Over the years, I’ve also added the `-D` flag to my function, which shows the runtime of the command in history. (This is again dependent on `EXTENDED_HISTORY`.) Plus, I’ve renamed the function to `hgrep`, which I find easier to remember:

```
hgrep () { fc -Dlim "*$@*" 1 }
```

Comment: Better yet is to use "\*$@\*" (note additional stars) pattern instead of "$@" as the latter yields only exact matches.

Comment: You’re completely right, @PiotrDobrogost! I’m not sure how I managed to submit this answer in the state that I did — I’m guessing I must’ve typed that function from memory. As it stands it’s not very usable, so I’m going to edit the answer to incorporate the asterisks.

Comment: I just switched to zsh from bash, this helped me out. I wished I had this tip years ago. All that time I've been foolishly using grep.

Comment: Using grep is certainly not "foolish", @Halfstop. In fact, I would say it's the obvious thing to do, and probably how most people would accomplish this task daily. My answer is more of a "zsh insider alternative". (But it turns out that it does have certain advantages, as I pointed out in the edit I made to the answer in January this year.)

Comment: The 2nd quote in the last command is probably a typo.

Comment: @TeddyC Yeah I have no idea how that crept in. Fixed; thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: if you’re calling it `hgrep`, wouldn't it be better to write it something like `hgrep() { fc -Dli 1 | grep $@ }`? EDIT: I tried this and it’s quite slow, compared to other methods. Must be decoding -Di before feeding to grep.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). It helps not only finding "whatever-particles" in your shell history, but also in other interesting places, e.g. browser history, directory history, etc.

fzf is a command-line fuzzy finder. That means you can search for particles or fractions of what you are looking for and it will display a collection of matches which you can continuously refine. It's really a game changer.

The [homepage](https://junegunn.kr/) of the author contains a number of illustrative examples.

Comment: Consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Using FZF with History

Including the suggestion from other threads here I found the best way (for me at least) to achieve searching my history using `fzf`.

1. Ensure you have already installed `fzf` first, also you will need `bat`.
2. Configure your `fzf` as (put this in your alias)

```bash
 #########################################################
#             CHECK THE BINARY OF FZF
# URL: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/\
# FAQ.md#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon
#########################################################
case $(uname -s) in
"Darwin")
  if [ "$(uname -m)" = "arm64" ]; then
    fzf_binary="/opt/homebrew/bin/fzf"
  elif [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]; then
    fzf_binary="/usr/local/bin/fzf"
  fi
  ;;
"Linux")
  if [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]; then
    fzf_binary="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/fzf"
  fi
  ;;
esac

alias fzf="$fzf_binary --preview-window top:30 --preview '([[ -f {} ]] && (bat --style=numbers --color=always\
     {} || bat {})) || ([[ -d {} ]] && (tree -C {} | less)) || echo {} 2> /dev/null | head -200'"
```

3. Pip the `history 0`  to the `fzf` using

```sh
history 0 | fzf
```

You should be able smoothly to find any command in the past
[image]